# CJ1W-CT021 Card Error Omron PLC

Tags: plc

I got this error on a CJ1W-CT021 card.  It happen all of a sudden after its been running the program for some time.  How i found it was by going to the IO Table and Unit Set up. Clicked on parameters for that card and found two settings in red.

Output Control Mode and And/Or Counter Output Patterns. This was there reading

```
Output Control Mode = 0x40 No Applicable Set Data
And/Or Counter Output Patterns = 0x64 No Applicable Set Data
```

no idea on how or why these would change they should of been

```
 Output Control Mode = Range Mode
 And/Or Counter Output Patterns = Logically Or
```

I have added some new code, but nothing big or really even used as i had the outputs of the new rungs jumped out.  One thing i thought might cause this is every cycle of the program it was checking the value of an encoder connected to this card. Maybe checking it too offten?  Anyhow if anyone has any idea what these do or how they would change please post.
Thanks
Glen

EDIT..  I wanted to add the bits i used, dont think any are part of this cards internal io but i may  be wrong?

```
Work bits 66.01 - 66.06 , 60.02 - 60.07 , 160.12, 160.01 - 160.04, 161.02, 161.03
```

and

```
Data Bits (D)20720, 20500, 20600, 20000, 20590, 20040
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would check section 4-1 through 4-2-4 of the [CT021 manual](http://downloads.industrial.omron.eu/IAB/Products/Automation%20Systems/PLCs/Modular%20PLC%20Series/CJ2M/CJ1%20Position%20Control%20Units/W401/W401-E1-03+CJ1W-CT021+OperManual.pdf) - make sure you aren't writing to reserved memory locations used for configuration data of the CT021 unit.

EDIT:

1)  Check Page 26 of the above manual to see the location of the machine switch settings.  The bottom dial sets the '1's digit and the top dial sets the '10's digit (ie machine number can be 0-99);

2)  Per page 94, D-Memory is allocated from `D20000 + (N X 100)` (400 Words) where N is equal to the machine number.

I would guess that your machine number is set to 0 (ie: both dials at '0'), 5, or 6.  In the case of machine number '0', this would make the reserved DM range `D20000 -> D20399`.  In this case (see pages 97, 105) `D20000` would contain configuration data for `Output Control Mode` (bits 00-07) and `Counter Output Patterns` (bits 08-15).  It looks like you are writing `0x6440` to `D20000` (or D20500, D20600 for machine number 5 or 6, respectively) and are corrupting the configuration data.

If your machine number is 0 then stay away from `D20000-D20399` unless you are directly trying to modify the counter's configuration state (ie: don't use them in your program!).

If the machine number is 1 then likewise for `D20100-D20499`, etc.  If you have multiple counters they can overlap ranges so they should always be set with machine numbers which are 4 apart from each other.

Comment: thanks looking now. also added what bits iam using in original post.. maybe you can see something i am missing.

Comment: Great information!  And Should solve my issue , i will be looking at this tonight.  I was wondering how to get the machine number. that part helped alot!  Now on to find a replacement data memory i can use..

Comment: Also just checked and machine numbers are 0, 4, and 8   thus D20000 - D20399 cant be used,  D20400 - D20799 ,  and D20800 - D21199   So pretty much i need to change all the D locations.

Comment: @GlenMorse CX-Programmer has a great 'Cross-Reference' report page for getting a nice overview of the available and used memory locations (under 'View' menu).  I'm always in there when extending programs - select "D" for memory area and "usage overview, including unused" in the second pulldown.  This will generate a map of D-Memory showing used and unused locations.  It won't show you reserved areas, of course (you have to check manuals for installed units for that) but you should be able to easily find loads of free blocks to work with.

Comment: lol , nice i was about to ask that next. sucks about the reserved area not showing though. As the rack has about 8 cards on it..